# Web API Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type:

Tags: c#, list, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a `Web API` in I know there are lots of questions asked about it but I have tried their solution but didn't work for me. I am declaring a list which I will be using at several points in my list.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetDetails(string msn, DateTime dt)
{
   try
    {
          var mainDetails= new List<string>();

          int mainCount = giveMainCount(msn, dt);

           if(mainCount==0)
           {
              // here I want to set the list empty like mainDetails = null or "" like this
           }

            int mainInterval = mainCount / 500;

            mainDetails = kesc.tj_xhqd
                         .AsNoTracking()
                         .Where(m => (m.zdjh == msn) && (m.sjsj >= dt))
                         .AsEnumerable()
                         .Select((x, i) => new { MSN = x.zdjh, PingDateTime = x.sjsj, PingValue = x.xhqd, i = i })
                         .Where(x => x.i % mainInterval == 0)
                         .ToList(); // here I am getting error 
       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { details = mainDetails });

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
    }


    }
}
```

The error is

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string MSN, System.DateTime? PingDateTime, string PingValue, int i>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

How can I get rid of this error ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You're creating instances of an anonymous type and trying to insert them in a list of strings.

Comment: you are creating a list of object which consist of 4 different properties. how can you cast to a list of one type i.e string. Not possible. create a class of those four properties and cast your object into list of that class.

Comment: @Nadeem I am using `EF` and I do have a class `public partial class tj_xhqd
    {
        public string zdjh { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> sjsj { get; set; }
        public string xhqd { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: @Nadeem then in my `DB Context` I have `public virtual DbSet<tj_xhqd> tj_xhqd { get; set; }`

Comment: @Nadeem Then I am using `tj_xhqd` in my controller

Comment: instead of list<string> create instance of list<tj_xhqd >

Comment: and in the select part of your query ".Select((x, i) => new { MSN = x.zdjh, PingDateTime = x.sjsj, PingValue = x.xhqd, i = i })" replace it with

Comment: `var mainDetails= new List<tj_xhqd>();` gives me `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string MSN, System.DateTime? PingDateTime, string PingValue, int i>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ActualWebService.Models.tj_xhqd>'`

Comment: @Nadeem " replace it with" with what ?

Comment: with this .select((x,i) => new tj_xhqd { zdjh = x.zdjh, sjsj = x.sjsj, xhqd= x.xhqd, i = i  }

Comment: @Nadeem I need to have the aliases that why i am using them

Comment: Remove `var mainDetails= new List<string>();` and further down the code change `mainDetails =` to `var mainDetails =`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

You could go with not declaring `mainDetails` from the beginning, doing something like:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetDetails(string msn, DateTime dt)
{
    try
    {
        int mainCount = giveMainCount(msn, dt);

        if (mainCount == 0)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { details = null });
        }

        int mainInterval = mainCount / 500;

        var mainDetails = kesc.tj_xhqd
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .Where(m => (m.zdjh == msn) && (m.sjsj >= dt))
                        .AsEnumerable()
                        .Select((x, i) => new { MSN = x.zdjh, PingDateTime = x.sjsj, PingValue = x.xhqd, i = i })
                        .Where(x => x.i % mainInterval == 0)
                        .ToList();

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { details = mainDetails });

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
    }
}
```

Doing it this way, `mainDetails` will be what you want, a `List` of that anonymous type with aliases.

---

### Option 2

As an alternative option, you could create a class for the aliases (use what you want instead of `AliasClassName`):

```
public class AliasClassName
{
    public string MSN { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> PingDateTime { get; set; }
    public string PingValue { get; set; }
    public int i { get; set; }
}
```

Then declare `mainDetails` as a `List` of that:

```
var mainDetails = new List<AliasClassName>();
```

And then do:

```
.Select((x, i) => new AliasClassName { MSN = x.zdjh, PingDateTime = x.sjsj, PingValue = x.xhqd, i = i })
```

Comment: `Option 1` I already used it but it was useless for me. As for `Option 2` I have found the solution. Anyways thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution and it works for me

Changed

```
var mainDetails= new List<tj_xhqd>();
```

To

```
IEnumerable mainDetails= new List<tj_xhqd>();
```

By doing this I got rid of my error

For further details, one can check it [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/508248/Cannotplusimplicitlyplusconvertplustypeplus-Syst)